# ROS2 to ESP32 - Wifi MQTT vs Websocket

Tags: c++, websocket, mqtt, ros, esp32

We're building up an architecture from a central PC running ROS2 nodes (in Python) communicating to edge hardware controlling a variety of motors and sensors.

Speed is critical when communicating to motors and we hope to be in the 10s of `ms` range for messages between our ESP32 controllers and the ROS nodes.

Networking is wireless and we have a good router and stable Wifi connection always between edge and core nodes. We built the initial system over `MQTT`, running a `broker` on the core PC and the ESP32s initiating `client` connections.

We found that the `MQTT` broker was inconsistent and would not always clear node names - meaning, clients trying to re-connect would be rejected (they require unique IDs). We also experienced a certain `buffering` or `queueing` of messages. This caused crashes/reboots of the ESP32s and ultimately motor control issues.

The latest idea was to abandon `MQTT` (as it is not designed to keep connections open over long periods, rather handle many IoT clients distributed over time - my limited understanding). Instead we are running a `Websocket` server in Python (compiled by ROS2) and ESP32s create a connection. So far it has proved faster and simpler.

However, after some time the ESP32 seems to throw a wobbly (not to the extent where it panics and reboots), but some kind of buffer seems to fill up. This causes the server to reject the connection and all subsequent communication even when implementing a `reconnect` functionality in the ESP32.

My suspicion is that we are doing a lot in the ESP (it also handles PID and CAN communication to motor controllers) and not 100% in control of memory handling. After a period of running pretty fast - `10s` of `ms` - the server experiences the connection loss exceptions.

Below is the main loop of the ESP32 client code.

```
#include <driver/can.h>
#include <driver/gpio.h>
#include <esp_system.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <PID_v1.h>


//================================LOOP=======================================

void loop()
{
  //read values from VESC
    can_read();
    comm_can_set_duty(duty);
    positionState = !digitalRead(positionSwitch);
    if (calibrated == true){
      if (millis()-last_calc > throttle){
        myPID.Compute();
        Input = (tacho_pos - tachometer_end) *calibrated_step+angle_offset;
        duty = Output;
        last_calc = millis();
    }
  }
  
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  // if WiFi is down, try reconnecting every CHECK_WIFI_TIME seconds
  if ((WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)) {
    Serial.println("Reconnecting to WiFi...");
    WiFi.disconnect();
    WiFi.reconnect();
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    if (client.available()) {
      client.poll();
      if (millis() - last_calc_in > throttle) { // request a new msg every 10ms
        client.send(String(Setpoint));
        last_calc_in = millis();
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("WS not available - reconnecting");
      client.close();
      client.connect(websockets_server_host, websockets_server_port, "/");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  if (millis() - previousMillis > 20)  // send out your CAN frame once every 20 ms
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < my_message.data_length_code; i++) {
      my_message.data[i] = buffer_[i];
    }
    can_transmit(&my_message, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    previousMillis = millis();
  }
}
```

Has anyone got experience with this architecture or hardware combination? Perhaps running multiple resource intensive tasks on an ESP32? Where would you spend time investigating?

Many thanks.

Comment: MQTT - `"as it is not designed to keep connections open over long periods"` This statement is just plain wrong, it is totally intended that clients should maintain a constant single connection to the broker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what's constraining your solution. It could be RAM, CPU, network, bad architecture (i.e. you're tripping yourself).

For heap memory, you can call [`xPortGetFreeHeapSize()`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/heap_debug.html#heap-information) to see available heap. If it's steadily decreasing during the lifetime of your program, you're leaking.

For stack memory, you can check whether the stacks of all tasks are staying within their allocated stack sizes by calling [`uxTaskGetSystemState()`](https://www.freertos.org/uxTaskGetSystemState.html) to get the status of all tasks in the system and their unused stack amount. My strategy is to make sure every task has 1KB of stack is available after running for a good while.

For monitoring CPU usage, the same function `uxTaskGetSystemState()` will report the time each task has been scheduled to run.

I'm using this snippet to report the status (most importantly the stack and runtime) of all tasks in my system. If you're suspecting one of those two as the culprit, run something similar every couple of seconds to see if anything is hogging the stack or CPU. Note that the runtime durations are stored as microseconds inside a 32-bit unsigned integer so they will overflow every 4294 seconds.

```
    static TaskStatus_t tasks[MAX_TASKS];
    unsigned int rt;
    const size_t taskCount = uxTaskGetNumberOfTasks();
    if (MAX_TASKS < taskCount) {
        printf("buffer %u insufficient for %u tasks", MAX_TASKS, taskCount);
    } else {
        printf("Tasks: %u", taskCount);
        UBaseType_t ret = uxTaskGetSystemState(tasks, MAX_TASKS, &rt);
        assert(ret);
        printf(" uptime: %u s\n", rt / 1000000);
        const float rtPctDivisor = rt / 100.0;
        for (UBaseType_t i = 0; i < ret; i++) {
            const float taskRtPct = rt ? tasks[i].ulRunTimeCounter / rtPctDivisor : 0.0;
            printf("%16s hnd: %08x num: %2u state: %s pri: %02u/%02u min_free: %4u cpu: %5.2f%% (%u s)\n",
                tasks[i].pcTaskName,
                reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(tasks[i].xHandle),
                tasks[i].xTaskNumber,
                mapTaskState[tasks[i].eCurrentState],
                tasks[i].uxCurrentPriority,
                tasks[i].uxBasePriority,
                tasks[i].usStackHighWaterMark,
                taskRtPct,
                tasks[i].ulRunTimeCounter / 1000000
            );
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    }
```

Output:

```
Tasks: 21 uptime: 3462 s
           Uart0 hnd: 3ffe98bc num: 25 state: run pri: 12/12 min_free: 3016 cpu:  0.01% (0 s)
            IDLE hnd: 3ffbd57c num:  7 state: rdy pri: 00/00 min_free: 1788 cpu: 97.49% (3375 s)
            IDLE hnd: 3ffbd414 num:  6 state: rdy pri: 00/00 min_free: 1776 cpu: 60.07% (2079 s)
         GicLoop hnd: 3ffe3848 num: 23 state: blk pri: 00/00 min_free: 1840 cpu:  3.76% (130 s)
         Tmr Svc hnd: 3ffbd6e4 num:  8 state: blk pri: 01/01 min_free: 3368 cpu:  0.06% (2 s)
...
```

You might also simply be transmitting more packets than the tiny network stack can process. Have a look at [how to optimize performance](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/lwip.html#performance-optimization). You don't actually check for any errors when sending. It's worth doing this as you're probably near the limits of what the ESP32's WiFi can do. Try disabling the [WiFi power saving](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_wifi.html#_CPPv415esp_wifi_set_ps14wifi_ps_type_t) so the radio won't try to go to sleep between transmissions.

Finally, note that your choice of transport (TCP) is not really suitable for low-latency, real-time data sent very frequently. TCP is reliable and in-order, meaning if there's a package dropped or delayed, TCP will just stubbornly keep retrying to send the same package until its delivery is confirmed. All your other *fresh* data will be sitting in the TCP buffer, waiting for the retry to succeed before they get sent out. This can take time, meanwhile your data can become stale, the TCP buffer might overflow, etc. If you can tolerate (or work around) lost and out of order packets, UDP would give you much better latency and jitter.

Comment: Thanks @Tarmo. Very detailed and will help debug the client side - which is where I suspect the problem lies.

Your final point on TCP vs UDP is interesting and I'll look into it also. We care about latency over packet loss for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using esp32 and ros2 I would suggest to use micro-ros, Last time I used it for a similar thing latency was less than < 10ms

https://micro.ros.org/